# Cannot find/detect PS/2 mouse in old Debian. How to enable?

Tags: debian, x11, mouse, x-server

I'm trying to configure XFree86 3.1.2 on my Debian 1.1 (buzz) distribution, but after configuring XFree86, I receive the error: `Fatal server error: Cannot open mouse (No such device)` when trying to start the X Server with `startx`.
The problem doesn't seem to be with XFree86, but Debian 1.1 not seeing the PS/2 mouse device.
The [Debian install manual](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/buzz/main/disks-i386/1996_6_16/install.html) does not cover mice, and the manpages (`man mouse`) only pertains to serial mice.

I am using a Microsoft Optical Mouse v1.1 (USB) with the official Microsoft USB -> PS/2 adapter that came with it.  This works perfectly well as being recognised as a PS/2 mouse in MS-DOS 6.22 on the same system being used for Debian.

Serial mice are usually located at `/dev/mouse` but that does not exist (because I don't have a serial mouse). `/dev/input/mice` also does not exist.

`/dev/psmouse` exists and is symlinked to `/dev/psaux`, but when I `cat /dev/psmouse` I get `No such device`.

There is no `gpm` or `gpm.conf` that exists on this Debian version, and it's not old enough (June 1996) to pre-date PS/2 mice.  The Linux kernel is version 2.0.0.

If MS-DOS 6.22 can recognise this USB-PS/2 converted mouse as a PS/2 device, then I'm certain Debian can also.

How do I enable and configure a PS/2 mouse to be recognised in Debian 1.1. (buzz), so that it can be recognised by XFree86?

Comment: Anything PS/2 related in `dmesg` maybe? For instance I see `i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found` (and I have no PS/2 mouse).

Comment: Nothing PS/2, mouse or device related in `dmesg`.  Only information about VFS reporting.  Surely, the kernel already comes pre-loaded with any ps/2 mouse related module? But, how could I check this to be sure?

Comment: `Debian 1.1` is so freaking old I've no idea how its kernel is compiled and whether it needs any special options to enable PS/2. In the past the linux kernel required a lot of tinkering, read modules parameters to make stuff work. Maybe you simply need to `modprobe` something.

Comment: Is this http://www.vorkon.de/SU1210.001/drittanbieter/Dokumentation/linuxfibel/xf86setup.htm  available on debian 1.1 ?

Comment: Hi.  No, unfortunately, XF86Setup is not available in 1.1 and doesn't appear to be available until 2.2 (potato).  I have to rely on XF86Config.

Comment: Judging from [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.user/c/QK4uBZRH3jw/m/y2Xh8b23W1sJ) and [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.user/c/wLvT2BzMLIw/m/_tqtq4_XM7UJ), it appears the [special kernels](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/buzz/main/disks-i386/SpecialKernels/)  need to be used in order to have bus or PS/2 mouse support.  However, I first have to source 9 floppy disks for this before I can test if it is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian 1.1. installation, by default (kernel 2.0.0), does not contain a PS/2 driver.
An updated kernel (2.0.18) or special kernel is required, which includes the PS/2 module along with several other mouse modules: notably, Logitech bus mouse and Microsoft bus mouse.
Both the 2.0.18 and special kernels are included in the Debian 1.1 distribution, at */main/disks-i386/SpecialKernels/*

I installed the 2.0.18 kernel using #7 of the 9 available 2.0.18 kernel types (prepared for various different hardware support).

`boot_2.0.18_7-1440.bin`

Once the kernel was installed (as well as some additional font packages), I was able to start the X Server.

ADDENDUM: One thing I did note is, by default, the default installation of Debian messes up the installation and configuration of the 2.0.0 kernel image and headers within dselect.
This prevents any other kernels being installed correctly, as the default 2.0.0 kernel cannot be removed correctly.
So, I created a custom boot/recovery disk from within the Linux setup, which used the 2.0.18 kernel I had booted into from the boot floppy disk.  I then booted from the custom floppy disk, instead of the hard disk, forcing the use of the 2.0.18 kernel.
I then ran `cat /dev/psaux` and when I move the mouse, random characters are generated, indicating it works.
Without the custom floppy disk, booting from the hard disk uses the 2.0.0 kernel and `cat /dev/psaux` gives the original error: `No such device`

Comment: Impressive, earliest I have working consistently is Debian 3.1. Nice going.

Comment: I was happy with the end result.  I even managed to get xquake to run windowed (albeit briefly).